# How to fill the remaining space in a Stack Chakra-UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

Is there a way i can make this work? Since flex={1} doesn't do the job?

Or else are there better ways to achieve the same ?

```js
<HStack w='full' spacing={2} bg='yellow.50' align='flex-start'>
  <VStack align='flex-start' h='full'>
        <Box w={20} h={20} bg='blue.200' class="fixed height element" />
        <Box w='20' h='full' bg='green.200' flex={1} class="Fill the remaining height" />
  </VStack>
  <VStack w='full'>
        <Box h={20} w='full' bg='red.100' />
        <Box h={20} w='full' bg='red.300' />
        <Box h={20} w='full' bg='red.500' />
  </VStack>
</HStack>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure If I get it right or wrong. The 1st `VStack` (green section) already fills the remaining space, so your problem is how the 2nd `VStack` fills the remaining space?

If yes, then the below code should work for you. Provide the height (h="full") to 2nd `VStack` and the last `Box` with `h="full"` will fill the remaining space.

```js
<Grid minH="100vh" p={3}>
    <HStack w="full" spacing={2} bg="yellow.50" align="flex-start">
    <VStack align="flex-start" h="full">
        <Box w={20} h={20} bg="blue.200" class="fixed height element" />
        <Box w="20" h="full" bg="green.200" class="Fill the remaining height" />
    </VStack>
    <VStack w="full" h="full">
        <Box h={20} w="full" bg="red.100" />
        <Box h={20} w="full" bg="red.300" />
        <Box h="full" w="full" bg="red.500" />
    </VStack>
    </HStack>
</Grid>
```

---

USING only flexbox, Box with flexGrow: 1 to occupy all the remaining space

```
<HStack w="full" minH="100vh" alignItems="stretch" spacing={2} bg="yellow.50" align="flex-start">
    <VStack align="flex-start">
        <Box w={20} h={20} bg="blue.200" class="fixed height element" />
        <Box
            w="20"
            flexGrow="1"
            bg="green.200"
            class="Fill the remaining height"
        />
    </VStack>
    <VStack w="full" h="full">
        <Box h={20} w="full" bg="red.100" />
        <Box h={20} w="full" bg="red.300" />
        <Box h={20} w="full" bg="red.500" />
    </VStack>
</HStack>
```

Comment: <Box w="20" h="full" bg="green.200" class="Fill the remaining height" /> this doesn't work, it doesn't fill the parent even after adding flex={1} it just stays and doesn't fill.

Comment: still not quite sure your problem. You can see the image, the green section is filled. https://drive.google.com/file/d/15W7wTDMGT0JOmFCnZtQJ884qoRMosIdO/view?usp=sharing. Your green area is not taking up all the space?

Comment: Thanks it helped I was not giving constant "vh" to parent element. I have to see what flex props Grid uses since using VStack instead of Grid again fails.

Comment: ic. i updated the answer. see if it is what you want. only use your HStack and VStack without extra Grid